# Add class to HTML element if input is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a class to `.form-group` if the closest `hotelObj` is checked and remove the class if `hotelObj` is not checked.

I want to use `css()` here instead of `addClass()`.

```js
$(".form-group").click(function() {
  if ($(this).children(".hotelObj").is(":checked")) {
    $(this).css("backgroundColor", "pink");
    alert("fungiuje")
  } else {
    $(this).css("backgroundColor", "transparent");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="form-group" for="male1" style="font-weight:800;float: left;">
  <div>
    Header
    <input type="radio" value="z5" id="male1" class="hotelObj" name="hotelType" >
    </div>
  <p>something</p>
</label>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What you are trying to do with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *code-form* that I encounter regularly.

We wish to apply a class to the clicked element (or to its parent), but also want to remove that class from previously-clicked elements *(so that only one such element has the class at any given time)*. This same strategy/code-form is also used to make checkboxes or DIVs behave like radio buttons.

It is this simple:

We begin by removing the class from all `.form-group` elements -- and then apply it to the just-clicked `form-group`.

```js
$('.hotelObj').click(function(){
    $('.form-group').removeClass('bgPink');
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') ){
        $(this).closest('.form-group').addClass('bgPink');
    }
});
```

```css
.bgWheat{background:pink;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="form-group" for="male1" style="font-weight:800;float: left;">
   <div>
      Header
      <input type="radio" value="z5" id="male1" class="hotelObj" name="hotelType[]" >
   </div>
   <p>something</p>
</label>
<label class="form-group" for="male2" style="font-weight:800;float: left;">
   <div>
      Header
      <input type="radio" value="z6" id="male2" class="hotelObj" name="hotelType[]" >
   </div>
   <p>something</p>
</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you're calling `children()` from the parent element, yet the element you're trying to find is a grandchild. You could use `find()` to fix this however there's a more semantic method.

You can invert the logic; put a `change` event handler on the radio button and set the class on the parent `.form-group` element, something like this:

```js
$(".hotelObj").change(function() {
  $('.form-group').removeClass('foo');
  $(this).closest('.form-group').addClass('foo');
})
```

```css
.foo {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="form-group" for="male1" style="font-weight:800;float: left;">
  <div>
    Header
    <input type="radio" value="z5" id="male1" class="hotelObj" name="hotelType" >
  </div>
  <p>something</p>
</label>
<label class="form-group" for="male2" style="font-weight:800;float: left;">
  <div>
    Header
    <input type="radio" value="z5" id="male2" class="hotelObj" name="hotelType" >
  </div>
  <p>something</p>
</label>
```

If you absolutely have to use `css()` instead of `addClass()`, which I strongly do not recommend, then you can do this:

```
$(".hotelObj").change(function() {
  $('.form-group').css('background-color', 'transparent');
  $(this).closest('.form-group').css('background-color', 'pink');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first assign the click event to the radio button and then check if that particular button is checked/unchecked, then add/remove the class accordingly:

```js
var classToAdd = 'some-class';
$(".hotelObj").click(function() {
  $('.form-group').removeClass(classToAdd);
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).closest(".form-group").addClass(classToAdd);
  }
})
```

```css
.form-group.some-class{
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="form-group" for="male1" style="font-weight:800;float: left;">
    <div>
      Header 1
      <input type="radio" value="z5" id="male1" class="hotelObj" name="hotelType" />
      </div>
    <p>something 1</p>
  </label>

<label class="form-group" for="male1" style="font-weight:800;float: left;">
    <div>
      Header 2
      <input type="radio" value="z5" id="male2" class="hotelObj" name="hotelType" />
      </div>
    <p>something 2</p>
  </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using jQuery's `addClass()` and `removeClass()` methods to a add or remove such a class based on the action